# How do I add a list to the master page?

Tags: list, master-page, page-layout

In WCM, I have a list (or two) that I would like to have appear on every page of the site using SPD. I would like this list to be dynamic, based on and existing list.

How do I add this list to all pages? Do I add it to the master page? To the page layout?

Is there a better way? I don't want to have to add it manually to every page.

Comment: I can't believe there is not answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

As usually the answer is it depends.

To show the list I'd probably use the ContentByQueryWebPart, but that also depends on what you need.

If you want the list(s) to show up on ALL pages in the same location (and you have an easy way of putting them in the right place using ContentPlaceHolders or directly) then adding it to the masterpage is the solution.

If you want them on all/most content pages then putting the web parts into the page layouts may be the best solution. But this may only affect new pages.

Adding the webparts to pages using code may also be a good solution.

And finally configuring the web parts to look right, then exporting them and adding them to the web part gallery will be a great solution for making it easy to add them where you want them on a lot of pages.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't create a console app that will add your list to every page of your site collection or web application ? it shouldn't be hard if you got visual studio and doing in on server where sharepoint is installed already.

Comment: I think if I have to do that my approach must be deeply flawed.